# Start in coverage mode for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, eclipse, visual-studio, code-coverage, eclemma

I am looking for a coverage tool for VS2017 `c#` code. Presently I am using [AxoCover](https://github.com/axodox/AxoCover) which is working fine. Here unit tests are to be written for the every lines of codes to be covered.

Now I want to test another C# project, I was thinking to get the code coverage by debugging. In Java [eclemma](https://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/launching.html) provide a `Launching in Coverage Mode` for Eclipse. Is there anything similar to that available for Visual Studio?

Comment: If what you have is working fine why look for something else? But anyway, some editions of VS have coverage analysis built-in.

Comment: With `eclemma`, we can have code coverage by debugging - without writing the unit tests. I wonder any thing similar to that available for `Visual Studio`.